# Non-writable dir with files inside of tar archive

Tags: linux, permissions, tar

I have a tar.gz archive that I can't extract because one of the directories doesn't have writing permissions at all despite having multiple directories and files inside. So I end up with the half-extracted archive, files inside of this dir can't be extracted because of no writing permissions.

How can I fix it without root permissions?

Comment: tar --no-same-permissions

Comment: same thing, tried this and --mode='a+rwx'

Comment: try: --delay-directory-restore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "delay-directory-restore" will set the directory permissions and time after restoring all the directory content:

```
tar --delay-directory-restore
```

Comment: What's the point of other options, they seem to have no effect at all. I think the answer should be just `tar zxf file.tar.gz --delay-directory-restore`

Comment: you right. the other options don't seem to change anything